# Power Distribution amongst connected nodes

Tags: lua, distribution

In my game the map is represented by connected nodes, each node has a number of connected nodes. The nodes represent a system in which players can build structures and move units about. If you're familiar with Sins of a Solar Empire the game map is very similar.

I want each node to be able to produce power and share it with all connected nodes.
For example if A, B, C & D are all connected and produce 100 power units, then each system
should have 400 power units available. If node B builds a structure that consumes 100 power units then A, B, C & D should then have 300 power units available.

I've been working on this system all day and haven't been able to get it working quite the way I want.

My current implementation is to first recurse through each nodes's connected node adding up the power, I keep a list of closed nodes so it doesn't loop, it's quite similar to A* actually.

Pseudo code:
All nodes start with the properties

```
node.power = 0
node.basePower = 100 // could be different for each node.
node.initialPower = node.basePower
```

-

```
function propagatePower( node, initialPower, closedNodes )
  node.power += initialPower
  add( closedNodes, node )
  connectedNodes = connected_nodes_except_from( closedNodes )
  foreach node in connectedNodes do
     propagatePower( node, initialPower, closedNodes )
  end
end
```

After this I iterate through all power consumers.

```
foreach consumer in consumers do
   node = consumer.parentNode
   if node.power >= consumer.powerConsumption then
     consumer.powerConsumed += consumer.powerConsumption
     node.producedPower -= consumer.powerConsumption
   end
end
```

Then I adjust the initial power for the next propagation cycle.

```
foreach node in nodes do
   node.initialPower = node.basePower - node.producedPower
   node.displayPower = node.power // for rendering the power.
   node.power = 0
end
```

This seemed to work at first but then I came into a problem.

- Say two nodes A & B produce 100Pu each, it's shared so both A & B have 200Pu.
- I then make two structures that consume 80Pu each on A (160Pu).
- Then the nodes power is adjusted to basePower - producedPower (100-160 = -60).
- Nodes are propagated, both nodes now have 40Pu (A: -60 + B: 100 = 40).
- Which is correct because they started with 200Pu - 160Pu = 40Pu.
- However now `node.power >= consumer.powerConsumption` is false.
- Whats worse is it's false for any structure that uses more that 40Pu, so the whole system goes down.

I could deduct from `consumer.powerConsumption` but what do I do if power is reduced elsewhere? I don't have the correct data to perform the necessary checks.

It's late so I'm probably not thinking straight but I thought to ask on here to see if anyone has any other implementations, better or worse I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, I think you are making it too complicated.

Your nodes can either be producing power or consuming it. And they can either have enough power or not. So can I suggest just having a single "power" variable and +ve is producing power and -ve is consuming it. Then you can calculate how much power each connected node needs with:

(pseudo-code, sorry I don't know lua)

```
node {
    int id;
    int power;
    node_list children; // This assumes a stingily linked list
}

node_list root_nodes;

// Gather a list of all unique connected nodes
void gather_nodes( node root, list & node_list )

    // Check the node is not in the list already
    is_already_in_list = false
    for node_in_list in node_list:
        if node_in_list.id == root.id
            is_already_in_list = true;
    if( !is_already_in_list )
        node_list.push_back( root )

    // iterate over the children and add them to the list
    for child in root.children:
        gather_nodes( child, node_list )

for n in root_nodes:
    int overall_power = 0;
    node_list nodes;
    gather_nodes( n, nodes )

    // Calculate the power
    for connected_node in nodes:
        overall_power += connected_node.power;

    // If overall_power is +ve then all connected_nodes have enough power
    // otherwise all connected_nodes do not have enough power
```

And of course you only need to recalcuate this when the power changes or you add/remove a node.

Comment: Thanks, this is a WAY more elegant solution. The gather_nodes method is pretty much the same as i've got but I never thought to simply compare the sum of power against the sum of consumers.